# golang how to split a string to a slice containing the delimeters using a regular expression

Tags: regex, string, go, split

I want to split a string to a slice but want to keep the delimiters. Is there a way to do that in golang?

For example

Input:

```
"Hello! It's, a? beautiful$ day* (today and tomorrow).
```

Output:

```
[Hello | ! | It's | , | a | ? | beautiful | $ | day | * | ( | today | and | tomorrow | ) | . ]
```

where `|` represents the separation of elements.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by creating a regular expression that matches either a word or one of your special characters. I don't know exactly what your rules are, but given the input and desired output, this works:

```
[A-Za-z']+|[*?()$.,!]
```

You can then use `FindAllString` to return the individual strings.

See https://play.golang.org/p/se6B74G_Fv.

The idea of the regular expression is to match either a word, here defined as a sequence of one or more upper or lower case letters or apostrophes, or a "special character", defined as any of the non-word characters in your sample input. The regular expression contains two parts separated by a `|`, meaning that either alternative can match. A set of characters contained within square brackets is called a *character class*, which means that any of the characters can match (and `a-z` means all characters from a to z). Since the left alternative is a character class followed by a `+`, one or more of the characters in the class will match. The portion on the right only matches one character. You may need to adjust this to behave exactly the way you want. For more information on Go regular expressions, see https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax.

Comment: Can you explain the regex? Is that saying any word that starts with a capitalized letter followed by lower case with apostrophe, and ends in some kind of symbol?

Comment: Added an explanation of the regular expression (and removed the unnecessary backslashes).